# Gridview paging not triggered in content page with jquery eventhandler

Tags: gridview, postback, jquery, paging

I have 5 jquery event handlers in my content page along with a simple gridview with `AllowPaging=true`. This has resulted in `__EVENTTARGET=","` in postback and `OnPageindexChanging` not being triggered. I have a similar scenario where in the Gridview events(delete, update, cancel) are triggered fine along with jquery events. So, I wonder what is stopping  the event handlers?

Here is my code:
This block is in document.ready

```
$("#searchByDateButton").click(function () {
    if (SearchByDateValidation()) {
        __doPostBack("SearchByOrderDate", "");
    }
});
```

Gridview looks like this

```
<asp:GridView ID="LensHistoryGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"    ShowFooter="true"
AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="LensHistoryGridView_PageIndexChanging" 
ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" PageSize="10" EmptyDataText="No Records found" >
```

Codebehind:

```
pageAction = Page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET").ToString();

protected void LensHistoryGridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
   BindGridView();
   LensHistoryGridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
   LensHistoryGridView.DataBind();            
}
```

Experts please suggest a way to sort this out.

Comment: Provide your full code ,Well as it seems somehow your page is being posted back automatically clearing your events ,So If you can post your full code that might shed some light .

Comment: Thank you for responding. Well, I have checked couple of things and found that if the master page is removed for this particular page it triggers postback and __Eventtarget != "," but here i need master page. I am not manually clearing the events anywhere in the page. Do you need further info?

Comment: Well if you can post your code that will be very nice ,See may be one can help if you can see your code , Right now only thing one can do is guess.Right now only thing we know is your event is getting flushed .

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your event ?Just place your cursor to paging as per the image and check your function and its `EVENTTARGET` and argument , and then on your `Page_Load` event check your `EVENTTARGET` value ..[image: Here] ,You may be able to catch the error.
 I needed to post picture so posted  as answer hope you don't mind .

Comment: Yes I did try this. If I place the cursor on paging then I get eventtarget as the gridview and argument is pageindex, but in pageload it is "comma". How can I get rid of this?

Comment: No problem with posting comment as answer

Comment: try to place `debugger` on all of your jquery functions  and check if somehow any one is getting invoked.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36037/discussion-between-suraj-singh-and-hima)